# Is it possible to check if a module is already included in RSpec configuration?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In a gem, I define a spec helper module that needs to be included in RSpec config.

Initially, we decided to let the user require the module file and to include it explicitly in `RSpec.configure` block.
Now we are going to change this behavior and automatically include our module:

```rb
# spec/support/my_mod.rb

module MyMod
  # ...
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MyMod
end
```

Is there a way to check if our module is already included in RSpec's config?
Checking [Configuration docs](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration), I don't see a method that could help here.

**UPDATE**: I have just realised that this is an uncommon scenario, because it's useless to check if the module is already included in the module file itself - the manual inclusion in the app happens later :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround solution. `@include_modules` contains  an instance of `RSpec::Core::FilterableItemRepository::QueryOptimized` which has `items_and_filters` method.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  included_modules = RSpec.configuration.instance_variable_get(:@include_modules).items_and_filters.map(&:first)
  unless included_modules.include?(MyMod)
    config.include MyMod
  end
end
```

```
> RSpec.configuration.instance_variable_get(:@include_modules).items_and_filters
=> [[MyMod, {}]]
```

Comment: Thank you @Yakov, it works. I don't like very much the idea of accessing an internal instance variable but if it isn't defined by the API I suppose we can do little :)

Comment: @Mat Indeed :-)